# Streamlit problem for filtering a selectbox depending on another selectbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, streamlit

I am trying to do a streamlit app in order to predict the price of a car depending on the values of some variables.

I would like to narrow the choice of model depending on the brand of the car. I did this code in order to have a list.

```py
#create input dictionary and list for categorical variables :
#for the variable Make
make_unique = df['Make'].unique()
make_dict = dict(zip(make_unique, range(len(make_unique))))
make_list = list(make_dict.keys())

#for the variable Model
model_unique = df['Model'].unique()
model_dict = dict(zip(model_unique, range(len(model_unique))))
model_list = list(model_dict.keys())
```

Then I created a function to narrow the choice:

```py
def filter_model(make):
    model = df[df['Make'] == brand]['Model'].unique()
    return list(model)
```

And I then created selectboxes:

```py
#start taking inputs
brand_input = col1.selectbox("Select Brand", make_list, help = "From which brand the car is made")
brand = make_dict[brand_input]

# for the variable Model
model_input = col2.selectbox("Select Model", filter_model(brand_input), help = "From which model the car is made")
model = model_dict[model_input]
```

However it gives me this error:

```
model = model_dict[model_input]
KeyError: None
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your code and with unique and loc, and you don't need all these filter functions. I left the second one with multiselectm but it works with single select as well:

```
brand = st.selectbox(
    'Select Brand',
    df.make.unique())

model=st.multiselect('Select your model', df.loc[df.make==brand]['model'].unique())
```

[image: demo]

p.s. i made it for my dataset, so please adjust column names, you have capitalized column names.